# What could I modify in this circuit to get 10 kV instead of 5 kV at the output?

Tags: circuit-design, power-electronics, high-voltage

We're doing a project to generate cold plasma. Our intention is to create an open-source, low-cost, portable device. For this reason, we're trying to avoid using commercial generators. Cold plasma generation needs typically 10 kV or more to work, at 10 mA or less.

While browsing for a solution, I found this article which is a 5 kV voltage generator. What would be the best approach in order to get 10 kV from it? Is it ok to try doubling this voltage or should we come up with a complete new design?

[image]

[image]

[image]

From this [paper](https://www.hardware-x.com/article/S2468-0672(18)30053-1/fulltext#relatedArticles).

Comment: Where is the 5 kV output in your schematic?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to find a different high voltage DC DC converter than the EMCO1. There are some that go up to 10kV in the same family. If that doesn't work you'll have to come up with a different solution.

[image]

But there are some companies that have an all integrated solution:

https://www.caen.it/subfamilies/up-to-2-kv-a750xb/

Comment: There are also some that go up to 12 kV, although with a 0-15 V input. https://www.xppower.com/product/F-Series OTOH, in the paper there is a reference to someone with plans to make a similar HV DC-DC converter.